# Missing argument 1 (Laravel method)

Tags: laravel

Here is my route :

```
Route::post('projects/addPolicy/{$id}/{$version}/{$language}/{$compContent}',  array('as'=>'digital_registry.projects.addPolicy', 'uses' => 'FooterSolutionController@addPolicy'));
```

Here is my method

```
public function addPolicy($id,$version,$language,$compContent)
    {
    print_r('inside'); exit;
    }
```

I am getting the error : Missing argument 1 for FooterSolutionController::addPolicy()

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is $compType, in your route?

Comment: First check through get method then see the response like so
Route::get('projects/addPolicy/1/2/english/whatever',  array('as'=>'digital_registry.projects.addPolicy', 'uses' => 'FooterSolutionController@addPolicy'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is $ sign with parameters. 
Use below code -

```
Route::post('projects/addPolicy/{id}/{version}/{language}/{compContent}',  array('as'=>'digital_registry.projects.addPolicy', 'uses' => 'FooterSolutionController@addPolicy'));
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$` sign in route like this.. This may work now..

```
Route::post('projects/addPolicy/{id}/{version}/{language}/{compContent}',  array('as'=>'digital_registry.projects.addPolicy', 'uses' => 'FooterSolutionController@addPolicy'));
```